# Add the name of a column to the following columna names

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to copy the name of the first column and add it to the names of the following columns, I don't know how many columns I will have because I am working with an application that generates data frames with different shapes.

```
Name      gene_1       gene_2       gene_n
00         01             02           03
```

Desire output

```
Name      Name_gene_1       Name_gene_2       Name_gene_n
00          01                  02                03
```

Comment: so you basically want to prepend "Name_" to each column?

Comment: Yes, copy the name of the first column and add it to the following. "Name" is an example, this will be a different string in each iteration

Comment: I mean, in each iteration of my application "Name" will be different as well as the number of columns. For example, the first data frame generated could be ```Pepe gene_1 ... gene_29```, second data frame generated, ```Juan gene_1 ... gene_10```

Comment: If you want to use different value for "name" just wrap the answer I posted with another loop where you iterate over the "names".
`for pre_name in pre_names:
// answer + you code`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be like this:
(can obviously be improved but should be fine for your purpose)
This should work for any number of columns, you would just have to update the `pre_text` variable, or use a predefined list of `pre_text` values that you could iterate over.

```py
names = list(df.columns) # get column names ['gene_1', 'gene_2' ...]
pre_text = "Name_"
pre_names = []
for name in names:
  pre_names.append(pre_text + name)
df.columns = names # rename columns
```